# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Update Lookup Field on Item

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer workflow in 2010. This workflow is associated with a list and when it is run, should copy the Current Item back into the list then update a field in that newly created item with a variable set at initiation of the workflow. Basically it duplicates an item then changes 1 value of the newly created item.

The field that I need to update is a lookup field into another list. For some reason SharePoint does not like this and errors out each time.

I have tried setting the value of the field to the following things, all of which fail when run.

```
ID of the lookup item
ID;#VALUE of the lookup item
VALUE of the lookup item
1;#201101 which is a hardcoded value I know is correct...just trying to test here
```

At this point, I am out of ideas. Can anyone help?

For more detail the workflow has 1 step with the following actions:

1. Copy item in Current Item to list at [Parameter:ListURL], Do no Overwrite existing items. Store resulting list item id in [Variable:DuplicateID].
2. then set [Variable:Reporting Month ID] to [Reporting Months:ID]. (this is a lookup into Reporting Months list using variable [Variable:Reporting Month] which is set at initiation of workflow).
3. then Update item in Current List (the item is determined by [Variable:DuplicateID] and I try to set the value of the Reporting Month field in Current List using various combinations [Variable:Reporting Month ID] and [Variable:Reporting Month]

The error I get when the worflow is run is below.

```
The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have had now the same problem and it seems that this is an spd-bug. I also wanted to write back the "variable: create" with the id of the destination-item into the lookup-field in the target-list. I also got always the same error. have checked the value also by updating a comment-field with this value and it was an integer value. but I could not update the lookup-value.

My solution for it:

Create a second workflow in the destination list that "update list item" in the target-list (update the lookup-value with the id of the current item) and define that the workflow starts automaticly by creation.

That worked fine for me. It needed some seconds more till the lookup-value was visible but this was not a problem for me.